# Problems with php/html "mail" function

Tags: php, html, email

(edited: i tryed to translate the code from portuguese to english and i amde some mistakes, but the code istill dosent wokr)

Ok, so i was just practicing a bit of PHp, so i decided to test the "mail" fucntion to see if i can send a email to myself trough the page im creating, but it is not working and i dont know how here are the codes:

This is the form File

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form to send email</title>
    <style>
        textarea{
            resize:none;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Send_to_e-mail.php">
        <p>Destiny(email): <input type="text" name="destiny" required/>
        <p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" required/></p>
        <p>Message: <br><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" required/>  </textarea></p><br>              
        <input type="submit" value="Send e-mail"/>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is in another php file(Send_to_e-mail.php)

```
<?php

$destiny=$_POST["destiny"];
$subject=$_POST["subject"];
$message=$_POST["message"];


mail($destiny,$subject,$message);



?>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong variables.

Comment: sorry i translated teh code too quickly because it was in portuguese, so i tought translating it in protuguese would be better

Comment: You can translate it into any language you want, just as long as you're using the same variables. Consult the answer given below.

Comment: You would need to change `mail($destiny,$subject,$message);` to `mail($destiny,$assunto,$menssagem);`

Comment: i tried that too, and the problem persists, i even used "echo" to check if everything was ok...

Comment: Are you running this from your own computer or from a hosted service?

Comment: im running this from my work's computer(sorry for terrible english), and it has wampserver instaled on it, i also ahve no idea o how to use it(i'm quite new to programing).

Comment: I run all my code on a hosted service, so I couldn't help you much with Wampserver. PHP needs to be properly configured and that `mail()` is also running.

Comment: So what **exactly** is the problem? PHP errors, mail doesn't arrive, something else? If I had to guess (*and I do, since the problem isn't described in the question*), I would think that mail is configured incorrectly and the mail is not getting sent.

Comment: ok..so its a server problem then...i'll try to look ino it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check your variables name**

You have wrote wrong variables names in your PHP code :

```
<?php

$destiny=$_POST["destiny"];
$subject=$_POST["subject"];//make changes here $assunto to $subject or viceverse 
$message=$_POST["message"];//make changes here $menssagem to $message or vice-verse 


mail($destiny,$subject,$message);//make changes according to variable name you have considered 



?>
```

Comment: I'd also comment saying to sanitize the input of the fields. Especially, strip out any commas `,`, because someone **will** (most likely) use this form to send out phishing/harmful/etc mails (However, I know that wasn't the question OP had (security))

Comment: thanks but i that was just a translation fail of my part, the code on my pc is unchanged and i check everything and it istill dosent work...